# When I use jQuery load, only the table gets loaded and not its contents

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-load

LandingPage.jsp has a table with a map in it. `content` is the div `id` in `home.jsp`.

When I say, `$("#content").load("LandingPage.jsp");` only the table border gets loaded and not the map or its content. Anyone has experienced this before?

Comment: you need to post more code, if you want to be helped.

Comment: and what's the output of LandingPage.jsp if you just access it via browser?

Comment: LandingPage.jsp has a map(arcGis) and a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by including the "Script" that is needed for the map to get rendered on the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2"></script>
```